# What does this line of code do exactly? (Prolog)

Tags: prolog

My lecturer gave us this sample program to look at the code, while I understood the recursive function on a whole the was this one line I couldn't quite grasp the meaning of

```
all_different([H | T]) :- member(H, T), !, fail.
```

extracted from the recursive function:

```
all_different([H | T]) :- member(H, T), !, fail.
all_different([_ | T]) :- all_different(T).
all_different([_]).
```

all I understood about it is that it splits a list into a Head H and a Tail T and checks if H is contained in T...My question is, what is it that "!" and "fail" do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These things are pretty fundamental to Prolog.

`fail` is essential. It forces Prolog to consider the current branch a failure and initiates backtracking.

The `!` is called "the cut." It commits Prolog to the current branch. Or, it prunes the trail of choice points under the current rule.

Taken in conjunction, in Prolog-ese, this says "If the head of the list is present in the tail of the list, there is no need to look for any additional answers, and fail." Thus, if any element of the list is present in the remainder of the list, you'll get an immediate failure with no chance of backtracking. This isn't actually all that dire, it just means that Prolog won't waste any more time trying to figure out if the list is "all_different." Backtracking will resume at the call site normally.

It's important that these go in this order. If you tried to cut after the fail, you'd never make it to the cut, because backtracking would already have begun. If you omit the cut, the predicate will return true if there is any sublist of the list which satisfies the property. This is guaranteed to be the case for any non-empty list by the last clause, which asserts that a list with one element satisfies the property. If you omit the fail, you're just going to get one success for each element of the list that is in a sublist, plus one for the tail. I encourage you to try playing around with the predicate, making these changes and seeing the effects, because it will go a long way to illustrating the purpose of the cut and fail.